# Ext way to create DOM elements, or minimalist alternative to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, extjs

I have a Sencha Touch application, and I want to create and append to the DOM dynamically for some custom HTML panels.

I *really* want to be able to do this:

`$('<div><p>Stuff</p></div>')[0]` to create DOM elements, but I can't find any such alternative in ExtJS. Does this sort of "create this big snippet" syntax exist in ExtJS, or is there a smaller library alternative that doesn't require that I pull in all of jQuery?

It also feels a little silly to mix two major frameworks.

Comment: Rly? You downvote every reply because they don't answer something that you didn't even ask for?

Comment: The answers are wrong and do not duplicate the functionality provided by jQuery. I asked for a replacement, and I was given broken, non-equivalent alternatives. These are wrong answers. Downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use jQuery. It's not that big.

Comment: Please only consider using 2 diffrent libraries/frameworks in the same project, it may lead to problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do it the same way that [jQuery does it](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2); create an element and set the `innerHTML` property to the HTML code, and get the children of the element:

```
var e = document.createElement('DIV');
e.innerHTML = '<div><p>Stuff</p></div>';
var div = e.childNodes[0];
```

Comment: If I use `<input>` elements, they don't render using this method. Something else must be going on here.

Comment: @StefanKendall: It renders just fine when I try it: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/9UALc/

Comment: @StefanKendall: That has nothing to do with the input. You can't put table rows in a `div` element. If you use a `table` element it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/9UALc/4/